# How to render charts properly when using Bootstrap Carousel and Chartkick?

Tags: javascript, css, html, carousel, chartkick

The idea is to use a carousel and instead of placing images as their content, to use charts (in this case using Chartkick). When the page loads for the first time, the chart that appears on the very first container renders without any issues. However, when I change containers on the Carousel, the other charts appear very small and not at the right position. I've noticed that when I manually resize the webpage, the chart loads correctly and the other ones inherit the problem, so I assume this is due to a rendering protocol of the Carousel that is not on track with what I was expecting. Is there any way to force a page resize when clicking a button on the Carousel? Or is it another way to solve that problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue the way I was thinking of initially. 
Here is the code in case someone has that same problem:

Javascript:

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#myCarousel").carousel();

          // Enable Carousel Indicators
          $(".item1").click(function(){
              $("#myCarousel").carousel(0);

              // The next line of code triggers the listeners for the page-resizing 
              // event, which includes the carousel and will display the chart         
              // correctly. 

              window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

          });
          $(".item2").click(function(){
              $("#myCarousel").carousel(1);
              window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
          });

      });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-numbers">
  <li class="item1 active">1</li>
  <li class="item2"       >2</li>
</ol>
```